# Linear independency in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying mechanical engineering and we are doing LA in higher mathematics.

I was preparing myself for the exam and stumbled across the following thing:

Show that:
$$v_1 =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}^T,
v_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 
\end{bmatrix}^T,
v_3 =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6 & 3 & 8 
\end{bmatrix}^T,
v_4 =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}^T$$

are linear indipendent.

My approach was to use the gauss-algorithm:

$$
    A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    1 & 6 & 3 & 8\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\to \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    0 & 4 & 8 & 12\\
    0 & 4 & 0 & 4\\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\to \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    0 & 4 & 8 & 12\\
    0 & 0 & 8 & 8\\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 4\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\to \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    0 & 4 & 8 & 12\\
    0 & 0 & 8 & 8\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefor, I concluded that those vectors are linear independent.

Then, I saw their solution and they did the same algorithm but they applied the algorithm to $A^{-1}$

My question now is:

> If n vectors are written into a matrix row by row, are the vectors, column by column, also linear independent?

Comment: From your question, I’m guessing that you meant to write $A^T$ instead of $A^{-1}$. There’s a big different between the two.

Comment: Oh yeah. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course, indeed for any matrix the number of linearly independent columns is equal to the number of linearly independent rows, and that number is defined the **[rank of the matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra))**.

Comment: Why is that the case? It sounds rather trivial but I do not really see the reason for that.

Comment: @FinnEggers It is not trivial indeed. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Proofs_that_column_rank_=_row_rank for the proof

Comment: thank you. I will accept asap.